# In Scala,why def not take effect after re-defining the variable used in the def expression

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation, read-eval-print-loop

As far as I understand ,in scala **def** is used to make an expression be evaluated lazily.

For example:

```
var num=123;
def  i=10000+num;
print(i); 
//result 1: ouput 10123

num=456
print(i) 
//result 2: output 10456

var num=789
print(i)
//result 3: output 10456
```

My question is,after `var num=789`,why `def  i=10000+num` wasn't evaluated to 10789.

I guess that after re-declaring the variable num by `var num=789`,scala re-create the other item in symbol table with the same symbol **num**.

Am I right? why the rsult 3 output 10456 instead of 10789.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scala def does not stand for lazily evaluated expression, it is function definition. So when you declare def i=10000+num you get the new *function*. When you then declare var num=789 this new 'num' shadows 'num' used in function i.

This may be possible only in REPL, if you try to make this trick in scope of the method, it won't compile, since var 'num' declared multiple times

Comment: yes,I run the code above in REPL.after testing,it can not run in .scala file.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are working in interpreter and when you do the second `var num = 789` you declare **new** variable that has nothing to do with the previous `num`. So your method `i` still references the old variable. If you write `num = 789` you change the existing variable, that's why the change is reflected.

Also `def i = ???` is just a method and not a lazy evaluation, although the behavior is somewhat similar. In scala you can use `lazy val i = 10000 + num` to denote lazy evaluation. It computes ones when you execute it, and then caches the result and do not recompute the value the second time